# I have series of file in OLD dir, I want to check if the file exist in NEW dir. If it does not exist, I would like to do few operations on it

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

For instance... I have some files in the format mmddyy.zip in the OLD directory...

```
041414.zip
041514.zip
041614.zip
041714.zip
041814.zip(today's file Apr 18 2014)
```

and I have a NEW dir with `041414.zip   041514.zip` in it...
I'm trying to copy all the files from OLD to NEW and do some other operations if that file doesn't exist in NEW dir...
I'm thinking of doing it ' while do' statement, but not sure what what to use in the condition...

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use find, and execute a script that does both the check and the operation.

For instance, script.sh (fill in your own variables):

```
#!/bin/sh
FNAME="`basename $1`"
NEWDIR="/tmp"
NEWFNAME="$NEWDIR/$FNAME"
if [ ! -f "$NEWFNAME" ]; then
    # do stuff to "$1"
    # optionally cp "$1" "$NEWFNAME"
fi
```

Then you run something like `cd /old/dir; find -name "*.blah" -exec script.sh "{}" ";"`